# Laravel 10x: Form Requests always return success message

Tags: php, laravel

I Have a Form Requests called `SignupRequest` that contain the following code:

```
 public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name_user' => 'required|min:5|max:100',
            'cellphone' => 'required|min:15|max:15',
            'email' => 'required|min:5|max:100|email:rfc,dns|unique:users,email_address',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max:100|confirmed',
        ];
    }
```

In my controller I have setup a POST method called signup:

```
public function signup(SignupRequest $request){
    $allRequests = $request->all();
    echo 'Great!';
}
```

If I set the return to `false` in the `authorize method`, and try to call the URL via the POST request (with postman app), an unauthorized operation error will be returned.

If I set to `true` and try to make a POST request (with postman app) without any parameters, I receive a JSON Response:

> {
> "success": true
> }

Wouldn't it be right to accuse which fields are missing? What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I am using laravel as a **REST API**.

In this case I have these two routes declared in the `api.php` file:

```
/* ROUTES FOR USER */
Route::post('/users/signup', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController::class, 'signup']);

/* DEFAULT ROUTE */
Route::get('/', function(){
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true
    ]);
});
```

I ended up discovering that this success message is due to a GET type route that was declared inside the api.php file. Despite this, whenever I call the route via the POST method, the request seems to be redirected to the GET route, is there a problem in Laravel regarding this?

Comment: I think you're not calling $request->validate() on the inputs

Comment: @AJZack request will be validated automatically with custom request class

Comment: I ended up discovering that this success message is due to a GET type route that was declared inside the api.php file. Despite this, whenever I call the route via the POST method, the request seems to be redirected to the GET route, is there a problem in Laravel regarding this? I update the post for more explanation.

Comment: First thing to check: Are you using the default laravel `.htaccess` ?

Comment: are u using @method('post') / method="POST" in your view ?

Comment: @AJZack, no I'm not using this project for views, is only a REST API. The all code I have is that you can see in the question. the laravel config is default. I just remove the ```Route::middleware('web')``` from RouteServiceProvider.php, and remove the line ```->prefix('API')``` from ```Route::middleware('api')```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an API request, then you have to set the header.

```
Accept: application/json
```

Now, Laravel will know that request is API then it will return JSON Response.

SignupRequest.php

```php
class SignupRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name_user' => 'required|min:5|max:100',
            'cellphone' => 'required|min:15|max:15',
            'email' => 'required|min:5|max:100|email:rfc,dns|unique:users,email_address',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max:100|confirmed',
        ];
    }
}
```

UserController.php

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(SignupRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();
        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'data' => $validated,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Success Response
[image: Response]

Validation error response
[image: validation error response]

**Note:**

1. If you are using a validation rule `confirmed` then you will have to add `password_confirmation` input field for confirm password.